# Vim binds not working in st

Tags: linux, vim, suckless-terminal

In my vimrc, I have keybinds set up for navigating through split windows in vim. They work perfectly in urxvt but refuse to work in st.

The code I have is

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-Up> :wincmd k<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-Down> :wincmd j<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-Left> :wincmd h<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-Right> :wincmd l<CR>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In both terminal emulators, check what is the value of $TERM. In st, you can alter the default value by editing `config.h` and recompiling; or temporarily change the value of $TERM.

Comment: If you aren't going to tell people in the question what the value of `TERM` is and what VIM has deduced from that in `:set termcap`, as well as what you have done to `st`'s `config.h` if anything, people aren't going to be able to tell you what to fix.

Comment: I did in the comment of the answer

Answer (score 2):

The two terminal emulators send different character sequences for the control/arrow-keys. If you've set **`TERM`** properly, most applications will work.

That assumes they're using the terminal database.

For reference, the two terminals would compare using

```
infocmp -x urxvt st |grep 'k[[:upper:]].*5:'
```

or (depending on the packager's preferences)

```
infocmp -x rxvt-unicode st |grep 'k[[:upper:]].*5:'
```

something like this:

```
kDC5: '\E[3\^', NULL.
kDN5: '\EOb', '\E[1;5B'.
kEND5: '\E[8\^', NULL.
kHOM5: '\E[7\^', NULL.
kIC5: '\E[2\^', NULL.
kLFT5: '\EOd', '\E[1;5D'.
kNXT5: '\E[6\^', '\E[6;5~'.
kPRV5: '\E[5\^', '\E[5;5~'.
kRIT5: '\EOc', '\E[1;5C'.
kUP5: '\EOa', '\E[1;5A'.
```

The control/arrow keys are **`kDN5`** (down), **`kLFT5`** (left), **`kRIT5`** (right) and **`kUP5`** (up).

Interestingly enough, *vim* doesn't use this information from ***terminfo***.  It uses only the ***termcap*** interface (which uses only 2-character names: these are not 2-characters).  Somewhere in your configuration, there's a workaround for this, which might be interfering with interpreting st's differing character sequences.  It might use the **`TERM`** value, but only in some hard-coded, application-specific manner.

Following up from comment, [**`st-256color`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-st-256color) copies [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_pcfkeys)'s behavior for the modified function-keys (and unmodified ones of course), and [*`rxvt-unicode`*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#no_urxvt) uses [rxvt](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-rxvt_pcfkeys)'s behavior for the modified function-keys, etc.  infocmp shows 138 differences between the two sets of function-keys (counting the modified ones).

Comment: I got no output from the comparison. The $TERM values are st-256color and rxvt-unicode-256color

Comment: Either you left out the **`-x`** option, or your terminal database has been corrupted.

Comment: I tried it on a virtual machine as well and got no output from the command you gave me. I'm really not sure what to do now