# ^PgUp/^PGDown for tabswitching are not working

Tags: vim, suckless-terminal

Vim has default keybindings for tabs navigation -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>

But in `st` they are not working, I suppose that the reason lies in `~/.inputrc` but I do not how to edit it.

My current inputrc:

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word


"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOH": beginning-of-line
"\eOF": end-of-line
"\e[H": beginning-of-line
"\e[F": end-of-line
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history  # PageUp key
"\e[6~": end-of-history        # PageDown key
```

```
user$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```

In vim:

```
:set term
# output
term=screen-256color
```

I had not changed st's config.h:

```
# will produce nothing
diff ./my_st-0.8.2/config.def.h ./original_st-0.8.2/config.def.h
```

Comment: As with https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572881/5132: If you aren't going to tell people in the question what the value of the `TERM` environment variable is and what VIM has deduced from that in `:set termcap`, as well as what you have done to `st`'s `config.h` if anything, people aren't going to be able to tell you what to fix.

Comment: I've changed `$TERM` to `st-256color` with no effect. Then I set it to `xterm-256color` and all worked. Is it right solution?